# Which field of physics is more evoloving and trendy?

Tags: discussion

I am a computer science student working on information evolution in scientific literature. Recently I found the `APS` [data-set](http://journals.aps.org/datasets/) which seems to be appropriate for my works. the data-set includes the following journals :

- Physical Review A: **Atomic,molecular and optics physics.**
- Physical Review B: **Condensed Matter and Materials Physics.**
- Physical Review C: **Nuclear Physics.**
- Physical Review D: **Particles, fields, gravitation, and cosmology.**
- Physical Review E: **Statistical, nonlinear, and soft matter physics.**

Using the aggregated data of all of them impose a high computational cost so I decided to choose one of them to work. In computer science some fields change very rapidly. Concepts rapidly emerge and vanish and some fields change slowly and the researches are rather classic. I imagine that the Physics should be fairly similar. I want to know which of this fields is more trendy and evolving over the time to show the evolutionary nature of science.

Comment: Now how is this related to Physics Stack Exchange?

Comment: I asked it here because the only people that can answer it are physicists.

Comment: This is the [Meta site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) for Physics Stack Exchange; this is where we discuss things about the [*main page*](http://physics.stackexchange.com/). Since your question is not actually about the site workings or policy, I've voted to close it. This probably isn't a good question for the main page either, though it *may* be okay to ask in [chat].

Comment: as you can see, nearly a zero tolerance policy for this type of "meta question" and its not strictly a meta question by SEs rigorous stds. but fyi [chat] can be open for nearly anything... ps "trendy" is not always great in science but quantum mechanics has a lot of lively/ recently evolving areas eg [computing etc](https://vzn1.wordpress.com/2015/12/18/qm-breakthru-google-vindicates-dwave-qm-computer-qubits-in-silicon/)